# Python won't tell my name. How can I make it to tell my name?

Tags: python

```
Name = input ("Hey, what's your name ?")
print ("So, your name is") + Name
```

The result is:

```
Hey, what's your name ?Robert
So, your name is
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Angel'94/Desktop/Sal.py", line 2, in <module>
    print ("So, your name is") + Name
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'NoneType' and 'str'
```

I would also like a space when I'm entering my name after the question mark.

Comment: Remove the parentheses.

Comment: `print ("So, your name is") + Name` -> `print ("So, your name is"  + Name)`

Comment: @mic4ael: which will cause a syntax error when using Python 3. And this *is* Python 3 because `print()` returned `None` and entering `Robert` into the `input()` prompt did not raise a `NameError`.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You need to *first* build the string, *then* pass the result to `print()`:

```
print("So, your name is " + Name)
```

What you did was first print `"So, your name is"`, and the `print()` function always returns `None` when it is done. You then tried to add `Name` to that `None` return value.

Instead of using concatenation, you could just pass `Name` in as an extra argument to the `print()` function:

```
print("So, your name is", Name)
```

and the function will insert a space between the two arguments for you.

To get a space on the prompt, just add it to the `input()` argument:

```
Name = input("Hey, what's your name? ")
#                  extra space here ^
```

Comment: Thanks, I've followed an old tutorial and I guess things are changed. Thank you very much and sorry for my noob question.

Comment: @RandiRobert: that tutorial probably covers Python 2. Be careful, things changed in the syntax. Either use a Python 2 interpreter for that tutorial, or find a newer tutorial that covers Python 3.

Comment: Yep. It's an old tutorial by Bucky.

Comment: Thank you for the extra space tip ! You're very kind Sir.

Comment: @RandiRobert Beware that Bucky is not exactly considered good education when it comes to programming, so take what you learn there with a pinch of salt. (What you learn will probably *work*, but it might not be considered best practise by experienced programmers.)

Comment: Oh, people on the internet said that he's one of the best newb-friendly tutors out there on youtube. Thank you for the tip. I'm just starting with python so I guess it ain't such a big deal now in the beginning.

Comment: @RandiRobert: well, I notice two codestyle issues that may or may not come from the tutorial: spaces before the `(..)` call paretheses and the naming convention for the variables. Both fly in the face of the [established Python conventions](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/). It is fine for now while learning the language syntax, but take into account that most Python code you'll encounter will follow different conventions.